# Facebook Graph API Group File Comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is somebody found way to read comments posted on the file in a Facebook group?

I can find all the files in the group with /files, but when trying to access files comments with file ID and /feed or /comments -heads I only get empty data set as results:

```
{
  "data": 
[
  ]
}
```